# How to create Custom Spalsh screen while Silverlight downloader download Application Library Cache files?

Tags: caching, silverlight, splash-screen

I have created a sample application suing Application cache, My some files are located on server. its working fine. But Now I have added appx 10 MB ZIP file and now want to downlaod, Silverlight downloader show 100% in xap download and then no progress show just circle appears.

I have tried the http://pagebrooks.com/archive/2009/02/19/custom-loading-screens-in-silverlight.aspx same and its working fine for XAP only. But I need it for "Application cache" files downloads

So is there any option to create my custom UI to show it at that time.Please let me know,

Thanks in advance,
Laxmilal Menaria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a Silverlight TV episode dedicated to a custom preloader... start from here...
http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/customer-preloader-silverlight-tv-006/

And see also this post:
http://elegantcode.com/2010/03/05/creating-a-custom-silverlight-pre-loader/

HTH

EDIT: 
OK now I got you. This seems like an open topic.
A solution is to provide your own logic:
this is a good blog post by tim heuer

http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2008/09/24/silverlight-isolated-storage-caching.aspx

Otherwise look for MEF and dynamically load XAP's (this would be my recommended way, too)
Because you got way much more control
check out these article
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/MEFDynamicLoading.aspx

http://www.davidezordan.net/blog/?p=1734

and gblock the mef master himself

http://johnpapa.net/silverlight/silverlight-tv-11-dynamically-loading-xaps-with-mef/

This open's even possibilities to cache, load on demand and split up you app in portions...

Hope I got you right this time...

Comment: I have tried the same and its working fine for XAP. My Application have enabled "Application Library Caching", but after xap download its show me 100% progressbar ONLY for few minutes, because its downloading Application library caching files after that.

Comment: I extended my answer a little bit... hope this helps

Comment: I have tried Silverlight application & downloading some assmebly parts real time. Now want to check its already in InternetCache or not before downloading, I have added this code. 

string tempFile = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.InternetCache) + "\\LM.zip";
          

But its give me error "File operation not permitted. Access to path '' is denied" so how can I solve it ?